# Local variables not being found (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, variables

[Local Variable not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/repwq.png)

```
writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "GyroData.csv",true), ',');
writer1 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "AccelData.csv",true), ',');
writer2 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "MagnetData.csv",true), ',');


String[] entries = res.split("#"); // array of values
String[] entries1 = res1.split("#");
String[] entries2 = res2.split("#");

writer.writeNext(entries);    //append entries to writer
writer1.writeNext(entries1);
writer2.writeNext(entries2);
```

However when debugging the values of entries, entries1 and entries2 cannot be found.
If it was just a debugging bug, the file should save to sd/storage/emulated/0/Download, but nothing appears as well.
The exact same code worked 1-2 months ago, now this is happening, so I'm not sure why, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
String res=((currentTime - startTime)/1000)+"#"+String.valueOf(d.format(gyro[0]))+"#"+String.valueOf(d.format(gyro[1]))+"#"+String.valueOf(d.format(gyro[2]));
```

Source of res ^

Comment: what is the source of variables res, res1 and res2?

Comment: Added to the post , they are the values of the sensors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your debugger is in the catch block any variables in the try block aren't visible.

The variable scope  is defined by the curly braces. Variables defined within on set of braces aren't visible outside that scope.

You need to step through the code in the try block directly or declare the variables outside of the try block.

Comment: See my answer for the explanation of the debugger.  The entries arrays are probably ok.  The exception indicates a problem in the IO operation.  You should log the exception or handle it.  It looks like your swallowing it from the screenshot.

Comment: Hi John, 
What I'm curious about is why the exact same code worked 1-2 months ago, but is not working correctly anymore?
I've read posts that leaving it blank would just ignore it. But none have worked so far.

Comment: The exception will tell you why it's not working, but that is a different question.  You asked why you can't see values in the debugger...